# Do I need a transit visa for 16.5-hour transit in LHR?

Tags: transit, tickets, transit-visas, lhr

In order to book a flight which has a connection time nearly for 16 hours in LHR, do I need have a transit visa?

I have gone through the https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa, to check whether I need a transit visa. But only thing that I couldn't figure out is the answer for the following:

> there’s nowhere for you to stay overnight in the airport, for example in a transit hotel

I haven't been to LHR before so I don't know whether they have facilities for overnight stay on airside. I have heard that if the transit is more than 10 hours usually we need a transit visa for certain connections (airports).

I just wanted to know whether **LHR has such regulations**?

Comment: Which terminal, and which 16 hours? I don't believe it is possible to stay airside at Terminal 5 overnight, for instance, so you'd need sufficient credentials to enter the UK.

Comment: I couldn't see the terminal before I book the flight. Anyway it's an international flight and 16 hours falls in night.